# How to Open console In geth 1.9.10

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, ether

I am currently using geth in windows and **1.9.10LTS** version of geth.

I have to Open **geth console**, but when i try to implement **geth console** or **geth attach** or **geth attach ipc:\\ .\pipe\geth.ipc** it doesn't work. Shows an error given below.

[image]

Comment: The first two error might appear to indicate a previous instance of geth is not running (Perhaps it is runnig as administrator or it is hanged). The last error message says there's other program listening port 30303 (likely another the instance of geth). What command did you use to launch the first instance of geth?

Comment: @Ismael No, I did not run as administrator.  I used this command for lauching my geth  > **geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath="geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc"**

Comment: The `--ipcpath` in windows only accept the name of the pipe. For example if you launch `geth.exe --ipcpath julia` you can attach with `geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\julia`. You are passing spaces, `:` and ```\``` in the ipcpath name so it might not work correctly.

Comment: So, What i shold do now?

Comment: Do not use `--ipcpath`, unless you have a reason, and use the default path. Launch geth with `geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net"`, then you can attach with `geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `geth attach`, you need to provide the IP:PORT

Example:

```
geth attach 'http://localhost:8501'
```

Your geth must provide RPC interface with something like this in the geth execution command:

```
--rpc --rpcaddr '0.0.0.0' --rpcport 8501 --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,admin,clique'
```

Comment: But when i declare port in **geth attach  "https://localhost:8501"** , it shows me an error. **Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: Post https://localhost:8501: dial tcp [::1]:8501: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.** @FlorianCastelain

Comment: @bignums Make sure TCP is enabled on this port. Make sure your geth is actually listening on this port. What is the command you are using to launch geth ?

Comment: I am using this command for launching my geth as so i am on the windows. **geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath="geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc"** @FlorianCastelain

Comment: @bignums You do not specify a port. Default port is 8545 if I remember well. Try ``geth attach "http:localhost:8545"``

Comment: @FlorianCastelian No, it also not working same error occur. **Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: Post https://localhost:8545: dial tcp [::1]:8545: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**